# Altium: possible to connect two repeated sheets?

Tags: schematics, altium

Can two "Repeat" ports in two "Repeat" sheets be connected?

[image: screenshot]

In other words, can I have a repeated sheet, where each instance has a unique sheet entry, and connect them one-to-one to the unique sheet entries of a different repeated sheet?

Using the names/parameters in the screenshot, all my attempts result in the compiler stating:

- `Unconnected Sheet Entry SheetA1-Repeat(MyNet)`

  - repeated verbatim six times
- `Unconnected Sheet Entry SheetB1-Repeat(MyNet)`

  - repeated verbatim six times

Which has thrown me right off, because I can't even figure out what I would name an interconnecting bus to try to resolve this, and my guessing is getting me nowhere.

All the guides I can find only ever deal with a single repeated sheet, but I thought the pattern was straight forward enough to extend. Alas, I'm stumped.

To be extra clear, if I was to do it without the second repeated sheet, it would look something like this:

[image: screenshot 2]

Answer (score 1):

By trial and error I found a solution. It doesn't seem logical, but it does seem effective. Even in a more complicated test case with multiple ports to be mapped of various types, I get no warnings or errors, and the rats nest when I import into the PCB is correct.

Simply name the adjoining net `MyNet_SheetB`, where `MyNet` is the sheet entry name and `SheetB` is the second repeated sheet name.

[image]

Of course, this seems a little arbitrary so YMMV, but at least it seems possible!